# Qualifications for answering: Are the days of stored procedures numbered

Tags: stored-procedures

Looking at all the answers to the question: "Are the days of stored procedures numbered".

It appears as if some people are jumping in with strong opions based on what I perceive to be a narrow range of software development experiences.

I would like to re-submit the question, but first I need help putting together a list of qualifications required before answering.

Here is one version of the requirements to get you started.

---

1. Worked on one large database like
   for ever (10+ years).
2. Starting some time in the 1990s went
   to work for a startup with the goal
   of creating a world beating ERP
   system.
3. Wrote code in either VB6 or Cobol.
4. Released new versions of said system
   once every 2+ years.
5. Came in as new developer of said
   system and had good the fortune to
   be allowed spelunk through thousands of lines of stored procedures so that some major changes to business logic could be implemented.
6. Worked deep in the bowels of a
   Financial institution adding web
   based front ends to various parts of
   large mostly ossified database.
7. Wrote more SQL code than many .NET
   developers have written C#.

Etc.

Comment: I think your answers will be few and far between by these standards...

Comment: Indeed, but I'm sure that if such a person could be found we would have a definitive answer.

Comment: X-) one persons perspective vs a community seems like dictatorship?

Comment: finally somebody asked this question .... again. i was waiting so long ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen the similar question [**Stored Procedures - End of days**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232141/stored-procedures-end-of-days) which has answers from some people I would consider to be some of the most experienced on SO in this area: Joel Coehoorn, Stephen A Lowe, and edits by Jeff Attwood (the OP refers to a podcast by Jeff where he says the days of SP are over).

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out.  I was hoping for a list of qualifications for answering the question.